# How to use user input using @QueryParam in SQL Query array

Tags: java, arrays, prepared-statement

I am really confused on how will I be able to make the where clause using @QueryParam. All I know is that @QueryParam is used to get the input of the user. I was not able to run it on my code. I have downloaded source code from codezone4 and make it as my trial. In this source code, I want the name to be from the user input. I know set parameter. But it is limited. How will I be able to put on the where clause the input of the user? Please I really need your help. :( here's the code I've downloaded

Access.java

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import dto.Course;

public class Access
{
public ArrayList<Course> getCourses(Connection con) throws SQLException
{
    ArrayList<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM courses where name = 'based on user's input'"); //here's what I want to know and clarify
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    try
    {
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Course courseObj = new Course();
            courseObj.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            courseObj.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            courseObj.setDuration(rs.getString("duration"));
            courseObj.setFee(rs.getDouble("fee"));
            courseList.add(courseObj);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return courseList;

}
}
```

Database.java

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Database
{
public Connection getConnection() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/codezone4";
        Connection connection = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
        return connection;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

}

}
```

Course.java

```
package dto;

public class Course
{
private int id;
private String name;
private String duration;
private double fee;

public Course()
{

}

public Course(int id, String name, String duration, double fee)
{
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.fee = fee;
}

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDuration()
{
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(String duration)
{
    this.duration = duration;
}

public double getFee()
{
    return fee;
}

public void setFee(double fee)
{
    this.fee = fee;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Course [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", duration=" + duration
            + ", fee=" + fee + "]";
}

}
```

AccessManager.java

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import dao.Access;
import dao.Database;
import dto.Course;

public class AccessManager
{
public ArrayList<Course> getCourses() throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();
    Database db = new Database();
    Connection con = db.getConnection();
    Access access = new Access();
    courseList = access.getCourses(con);
    return courseList;
}
}
```

CourseService.java
I this is where the @QueryParam should be used. I've tried using it

```
package webService;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import model.AccessManager;

import dto.Course;

@Path("/courseService")
public class CourseService
{
@GET
@Path("/coursess")
@Produces("application/json")
public String coursess(@QueryParam("puta") String courses)
{

    ArrayList<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();
    try
    {
        courseList = new AccessManager().getCourses();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        courses = gson.toJson(courseList);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return courses;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String course ="SELECT * FROM courses where name = ?"";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(course);    
stmt.setString(1,'your input here');
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried it. Thank you. :) but what I want is using @QueryParam. Because when I used setString, it is the exact value, what if it is run in android? The output will be the string that I set? For example, I want name : Koji. So, I'll use set string. If I implement it to android, is it always koji? Sorry for my english. Please help me. :(

Comment: I don't know whether i understood your actual problem but from whatever you said do you mean that you need to set the String dynamically?..If yes then in that case you can pass the value to your getCourses method. I haven't done development in android.I am saying this from java perspective.

Comment: I'll clarify my question. Im sorry. It's like scanning the user's input. When using web service, specifically logging in, it uses queryparam right? It is to be able to view if the inputted user was on the database? To tell you specifically my problem, I want to display the details on table where name is = input data. It is also by using queryparam. It is not assigning the exact data. Is it not possible? :(

Comment: Then i guess after logging in your queryparam will contain one user's input right? Assign this to some variable and then pass it to the getCourses method in your Access.java class

Comment: How can I do that? Can you give me the sample code?

Comment: Try this and check if it works...?user=<your user name> 

Then use @QueryParam as below 

(@QueryParam("user") String user) ....now use this user String in your getCourses method.

Comment: I tried to put the QueryParam in the Access.java where getCourses method is in but there is an error. It says QueryParam is not allowed there.

Comment: No put it in CourseService.java and then pass it to AccessManager.java and finally in Access.java

Comment: It still doesn't work. I put it like this:  public String coursess(@QueryParam("name") String courses)
 {

Comment: Check this link..[link](http://www.concretepage.com/webservices/queryparam-example-in-rest-web-service)

Comment: Sorry, I checked your link. Yes I was able to put the queryparam on the CourseService, but I can't call the String I used in queryparam to put it in the SQL Query. :(